Automatic bulk crash dump classification
I have 198 Windows crash dump files (.DMP) and I need to find out which ones are relevant for analysis.
IMHO, a crash dump should contain at least the following information:

name of the executable that crashed
version of the executable
exception code (like C0000005 for an access violation)
time of the crash

The tool:

should receive a directory as a parameter and then rename the files as {exe} {version} {exception code} {time}.DMP, or according to a configurable naming scheme.

must run on Windows

be gratis (open-source preferred)

should be a command line tool.

work offline (except for downloading symbols)


I have tried:

using a WinDbg script running via cdb. It's not fun.


Try BlueScreenView by Nir Sofer combined with Swiss File Knife by Juergen Thumm.  They are both excellent tools.  Highly recommended.
[x] CLI: Although, by default, BlueScreenView is a GUI tool, it also has a CLI mode (see "Command-Line Options" on this page... sorry, that section of the page is not currently directly linkable).  Swiss File Knife is a CLI tool.
[x] Gratis: BlueScreenView is gratis.  SFK is gratis for the features you will use.  Both authors accept donations here and here, respectively.
[x] Windows-compatibility: Both run on Windows (SFK also runs on Linux).
[x] Offline: Both work offline (SFK supports some specific online functions, but you won't be using those functions, and no connectivity is required for use.  You can firewall the executable, if you like.)
With a bit of cleverness, I'm almost sure you can use the two tools together in a batch file or PowerShell script to do exactly what you want.

It never came into my mind that BlueScreenView could handle non-bluescreen crashdumps as well. Worth a try.

Unfortunately, BlueScreenView does not analyze user mode crashes.

Ah, bummer.  Even though you have the .DMP files already saved?  Did you try the /LoadFrom CLI option?

Yes, I tried various command line options, and none of them worked. It seems it can only analyze kernel crash dumps (blue screens) and not application crashes.

That's unfortunate.  You can try to write to Nir to see if it's a bug, or if it's not, if he can add that functionality.  In the meantime, would you like me to delete my answer or keep it here?  I'm good either way... whatever you like.

I have now implemented UserModeCrashDumpInfo myself.

it works on windows (tested on Windows 10)
it's gratis, even open-source (MIT license), available on Github
it works offline and even doesn't need symbols to be downloaded
it's a command-line tool

It provides exactly the stuff I needed the most:

/exe gives the name of the executable that crashed
/fileversion gives the file version of the executable
/productversion gives the product version of the executable
/exception gives the exception code
/time gives the time of the crash

The order of parameters matters, so you can specify how the filename shall look like.
Other than that, it can directly rename the file

/rename does an immediate rename

The whole thing can batch-process multiple files, e.g. with
for %f in (*.dmp) do UserModeCrashDumpInfo "%f" /exe /exception /time /rename

